# add json objects to specific index - python

Tags: python, json

Today, I started with json an Python 3.x... So there are sill some problems. This is now my first important problem I have.

I'm looking for a fuction wich can insert (for example) this:

```
{
  'Current': '3A',
  'Voltage': '11V'
}
```

In to here:

```
{
  'Measure': [
      {'Current': '2A', 'Voltage': '11V'}
   ]
}
```

...so that my result is:

```
{
  'Measure': [
      {'Current': '2A', 'Voltage': '11V'},
      {'Current': '3A', 'Voltage': '11V'}
   ]
}
```

I only found functions in javascript to solve my problem, in python not. Till now, I saw only a hierarchical creation methode for json and nothing like a class and instance build up.

I hope, there are opportunity to done it. ;)
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution for your problem is to Keep the data as Python- Dictionary then do operations on it, later you can get JSON Objects.

```
import json
j = {'Measure': [ {'Current': '2A', 'Voltage': '11V'}]}
d = {'Current': '3A', 'Voltage': '11V'}
j['Measure'].append(d) # as it is list use append otherwise update
json.dumps(j)
```

Output:

```
'{"Measure": [
             {"Current": "2A", "Voltage": "11V"},
             {"Current": "3A", "Voltage": "11V"}
 ]}'
```

**EDIT-1:**

First append data to child dictionary then use dict.update to parent dictionary Hence solved.

**EDIT-2**

Exact answer is

`j['Device']['Measure'].append({'Current': '3A', 'Voltage': '11V'})`

it has to work.

Hope it is helpful ..!!

Comment: This is the right way. 
But I have to check that it also works in the third level or layer like `j['device_1','Measure'].append(d)`

Comment: Answer is updated .. let me know still you've problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to something like this?

```
>>> measureDict = {'Measure': []}
>>> measureDict['Measure'].append({'Current': '2A', 'Voltage': '11V'})
>>> measureDict['Measure'].append({'Current': '3A', 'Voltage': '11V'})
>>> measureDict
{'Measure': [{'Current': '2A', 'Voltage': '11V'}, {'Current': '3A', 'Voltage': '11V'}]}
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps(measureDict)
'{"Measure": [{"Current": "2A", "Voltage": "11V"}, {"Current": "3A", "Voltage": "11V"}]}'
>>>
```